# How to close sub window in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3

FullScreenPlayer.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using Windows.Media.Core;
using Windows.Media.Playback;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using WinUIEx;


// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace abc
{
    public sealed partial class FullScreenPlayer : Window
    {
        public readonly AppWindow appWindow;
        public MediaPlayerElement player;
        public FullScreenPlayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WindowManager manager = WindowManager.Get(this);
            appWindow = manager.AppWindow;
            appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
            Random random = new();
            player = new()
            {
                Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new($"ms-appx:///Assets/{random.Next(3, 6)}star-single.mp4")),
                AreTransportControlsEnabled = false,
                AutoPlay = false
            };
            player.MediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
            player.MediaPlayer.Play();
            grid.Children.Add(player);
        }

        private void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

using

```cs
if (localSettings.Values["Animation"].ToString() == "true")
{
    player = new();
    player.Activate();
}
```

I wanna close the `fullscreenplayer` when it has done,so I added a signal of `MediaPlayer_MediaEnded`.
But I found it doesn't work,Only the Window turn to black(be destroyed).
However,it can't be close.
I mean,can I close the sub window and let the mainwindow show again(the sub window covered on the mainwindow)?

I tried to use `Window.close()`,but is doesn't worked.
Then I tried to use win32 api,but it doesn't worked at all.
`DestroyWindow(WindowExtensions.GetWindowHandle(this));`
How can I do?

Comment: Are you sure MediaPlayer_MediaEnded is called?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I'm sure.I used to add test code like 'mediaplayer.play()',and the video loop.So I think there's no problem with calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call Close() on the UI (Main) thread but the `MediaPlayer_MediaEnded` event handler will be called on a worker thread. You can use the `DispatcherQueue` in this case:

```cs
private void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    this.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Can you accept it as the answer so we can close this?